# Error while using httpHandler.Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ihttphandler

I am trying to use HttpHandler in Asp.Net.I have made below changes in Web.Config file.

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*"path="Crm"validate="false"type="PracticeWeb.ApplicationController,PracticeWeb"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Also in ApplicationController.cs file

```
public class ApplicationController : System.Web.UI.Page, System.Web.IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

{
    public ApplicationController()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //..
    }

    public  void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
        // This handler is called whenever a file ending 
        // in .sample is requested. A file with that extension
        // does not need to exist.
        Response.Write("<html>");
        Response.Write("<body>");
        Response.Write("<h1>Hello from a synchronous custom HTTP handler.</h1>");
        Response.Write("</body>");
        Response.Write("</html>");
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // To enable pooling, return true here.
        // This keeps the handler in memory.
        get { return false; }
    }

}
```

I get the following error. on following line  of Web.Config

```
<add verb="*" path="Crm" validate="false" type="PracticeWeb.ApplicationController,PracticeWeb"/>
```

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'PracticeWeb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Url used to access the application.
http://localhost:1300/WebSitesPrac/Crm

Comment: Is `PracticeWeb` dll present in the bin directory of your web application. If yes, check the dependencies (assembly references) of this dll - for example, it depends on `xyz.dll` then `xyz.dll` has to be present in GAC or in the same folder (bin).

Answer (score 0):

The `ApplicationController` inherits from `System.Web.Page`.  Try removing this from the class definition and just implement IHttpHandler and IRequiresSessionState.

By deriving from the base type for WebForms your handler will be loading a lot of other types when it runs.  I am not sure if this is the root cause of the problem but it is a good place to start.